# User's password can not be set with passwd

Tags: 12.04, samba, password, users

I am running Ubuntu as a server, but with X-windows setup.  I have SSH , Samba and RAID 5 setup.   Was having trouble browsing Samba shares from my Windows 7 laptop, so I thought it might be a problem with the version of Samba and started installing Samba4.

Well, Samba4 was whole another bucket worms.  I managed to get the install process to partially finish.   After being frustrated I rolled back and reinstalled Samba3.

Ate this point I tried to create a SSH session with my user freak_storm and the password did not work.   so,  I went to the box and tried loxing through the X interface.   No luck.  I tried another user and it logged in.  I tried changing freak_storm's password with 'su passwd freak_storm'   ,but it just returns a command prompt.   So I tried with the current user 'passwd' and it asked for current password and command prompt.  I logged out and logged back in and now that user is broken.

So, I logged through the recovery panel and dropped down to root.
1) check password file and it's not corrupt
2) Re-installed the passwd package
3) deleted and re-installed passwd package.
4) removed Samba3 and re-installed

I'm now stuck.  I really don't know where to go from here?

any suggestions?  Should I do a fresh install?

Comment: Could you add the output of `grep freak_storm /etc/passwd`? Delete any (hashed) password strings before putting them here into the public!

Answer (score 2):

You need to first use `passwd [username]`.

Then you need to do `smbpasswd -a [username]` for a new user. Otherwise just use `smbpasswd [username]`.

Make sure both passwords are same.

Answer (score 1):

`su freak_storm passwd` and `su -u freak_storm passwd` are two different things.

The `-u` option runs passwd as the freak_storm user (which is what you want, I think).

Comment: I tried some of these solutions and some others.  Finally gave up and just re-installed.   It really bothers me to re-install, but sometimes bebuging can become,so frustrating I have to give up.

Having said that, I have a way better understanding of the how passwords are stored in Linux.